# Find replacement HVAC transformer

Tags: hvac, thermostat, 24v-transformer

I want to replace this HVAC transformer but I don't know any of the specifications or ratings for the existing one. This is hooked up to the heater in my garage/shop and the heater fails to kick on occasionally.

I found this question: [Are HVAC Transformers Interchangable (if their power ratings match)](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/91471/25178) but I have no idea what the specs are for mine. Are they pretty much interchangeable? Or is there a "trick" to figuring out what I need to replace this? Are there "doorbell" ones and "heater" ones? Is everything 24-volt?

[image]

The current transformer buzzes loudly most of the time when the thermostat calls for the heat to come on but also the left-hand screw is stripped so it regularly loses contact and prevents the heat from coming on. If I "futz" with the wires the heat will come on, but it doesn't stay that way. I suppose I could overcome the stripped terminal screw one way or another, but the loud buzzing is disturbing. I tried tightening the mounting screws and the armature screws and that only knocks back the buzzing for a couple days. So I figure it's time for a new one...If I knew what to replace this one with.

Also, a "side question" why is there an odd red wire on the left screw? What's going on there? Shouldn't there be another white wire around there somewhere?

Comment: If your 24 Volt transformer use two phase 240 Volt, kill it

Comment: @Ruskes Why? There are plenty of readily available transformers designed for 240->24, such as this one https://www.homedepot.com/p/Diversitech-HVAC-120-208-240-Volt-Primary-24-Volt-Secondary-40VA-Rating-Transformer-T1404/316327985 which can be wired for 120, 208 or 240. As long as it is wired correctly there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: There are absolutely ratings on it. You may have to remove it to read the numbers, since it may be on the other side. 

You need the same input voltage rating and the same output voltage rating, and the same or a little more VA (volt-amperes), but until you know what you have, everybody is guessing.


Also don't screw with the wires. Just put them on the new transformer the same way they're on the old one. If you don't, something will stop working.

Comment: @TerryCarmen - Yes. I found the ratings sticker. It was on the side of the transformer that was affixed to the box cover plate. Had to take it apart to get to it. Handy arrangement!

Answer (score 6):

The single red wire makes no sense. It may be a leftover from a previous configuration - along with a black or white wire that was removed.

As far as a replacement, the main consideration is voltage. Measure with a multimeter. Most common for HVAC seems to be 24V, but measuring is always a good idea. Anything between 20V and 28V and I would go with 24V. Below that, 16V is pretty common, but more for doorbells than for HVAC.

The other side matters too. That is usually 120V but sometimes 240V or (if you have 120V/208V service) 208V. Turn off the breaker, remove the transformer and the box cover. Then carefully turn on the breaker and measure the primary voltage. Actually, if a single breaker turns it off then you know it is 120V. But if it takes a double breaker to turn it off then this could be 120V or 208V/240V, and again checking it is the only way to know for sure.

There are plenty of replacements. You want to get something that, like this one, can mount on the outside of a junction box. Something like [this Honeywell from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Honeywell-Home-24-Volt-Transformer-AT72D/202264717):

[image: transformer]

Comment: Generally speaking, transformers that mount to junction boxes bring their own lid with them

Comment: What would be the double breaker size on 24 Volt 50 VA transformer

Comment: A transformer like this can be on (a) a separate circuit (in which case likely 120V single breaker), (b) a circuit shared with general usage (fine for a doorbell, not ideal for a thermostat because it would mean the thermostat and the rest of the HVAC don't shut down with the same breakers) or (c) shared with some other part of the HVAC system - in which case the breaker size would be determined by the HVAC system - could be anywhere from 15A on up.

Answer (score 5):

Any 24 Volt transformer will do.

The higher the wattage rating, the better to prevent overload.  A wattage should be in the range of 30, 40, 50 watts, and is  measured/labelled in `VA` or `W`.
Do not confuse with current, measured in `A`

Overload could be the cause of the buzzing.

Someone chose to use a read wire to feed as common (C-wire) to either the thermostat or another place. Should have been white or even blue, but that is all they had on hand.

Disconnect it and find out what is not working.

Comment: Feel free to roll back the edit - but I know some people confuse current in Amps and wattage in VA.

Comment: @Criggie what is the difference between Watt and VA (voltampere)

Comment: nothing - they're the same.  But a less-experienced person might not know that.   I've heard of someone confusing VA and A and getting the wrong thing in the past.